# How to remove a sub-theme?

Tags: themes

Is it possible to remove a *sub-theme* so that it does not appear in the theme list when invoking `load-theme` or `customize-themes`?

For instance removing only `doom-spacegrey` from the `doom` theme-set, while keeping the other sub-themes.

A related question is whether it is possible to install only a deliberate subset of sub-themes from a main theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doom-spacegrey` is part of `doom-themes` package. It's not a "sub-theme" but file included in package.

You can remove `doom-spacegrey-theme.el` from `~/.emacs.d/elpa/doom-themes-<version>/`. But it will appear again on `doom-themes` package update.

Better solution would be to add advice around `custom-theme-name-valid-p` function which is used by `custom-available-themes` to filter out valid theme names:

```el
(defvar my/blacklisted-themes '("doom-spacegrey"))

(defun my/theme-allowed (orig-fun theme-name)
  (and (funcall orig-fun theme-name)
       (not (member (symbol-name theme-name) my/blacklisted-themes))))
(advice-add 'custom-theme-name-valid-p :around #'my/theme-allowed)
```

Although theme isn't actually removed it will not appear in the list of available themes.